# How to move a material depending on animated curve end

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, shader-nodes

I have a simple open curve with depth - a simple tube.

I'm animating the tube to grow along the curve using the curve's Start & End Mapping parameters.

The default material is a diffuse black.

I'd like the active 'tip' of the curve to be a different emission material. Think of this like a reverse-fuse, where the emission end follows a set, short length of the 'lengthening' tube. In other words, the emission material follows the tip of the animated curve-end.

This video is a FAILED attempt. All I can do is possibly animate the Math node to limit the material-change to some cut-off point. But I'm looking for an automated way to define a set length of green that follows the end-point of the curve.

Lil help? Cheers.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3G0ZMVPBHM

Answer (score 5):

A "quick and dirty" way would be this:

- Double your curve, give one another color
- Give the other one on the end value a driver like this:

[image]
*<sup>click to enlarge</sup>*

Make that "other" curve a bit bigger so it won't overlap (that's the "dirty" part, and I am sure you can calculate this to be mathematically correct)

Result:

[image]

Comment: Good to know there's a mechanical option :) I am keen on finding a material option, mainly because I'm weak on nodecraft, and could use the experience.

Comment: i am sure someone will come with such a solution... ;)

Comment: I'm almost there, but each time I figured out how to do it Blender crashes :D

Comment: Try 3.1 …

Comment: I was trying to render the result, but that's when my PC crashes. Maybe I have to lower some resolutions ;)

Comment: you are a perfectionist.... ;)

Comment: @OroNZ I'm sorry I couldn't find a material solution. Just one with Geometry Nodes.

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one experiencing crashes with this. Admittedly I have some heavy geometry in this file, but I have 128GB of RAM - you'd think that would be enough...

Answer (score 1):

I've created a solution with *Geometry Nodes* in Blender version 3.0.1. The only thing that bothers me is that the node tree seems to be much too complicated for something rather simple. If someone can make it easier, you're more than welcome.

So I added a Bézier Curve, added a *Geometry Nodes* node tree and fiddled around until I got something working. What I wanted to achieve was: a different material for the curve's tip which is at the front while the curve is growing. My goal was to set the length of the tip in meters, so that it doesn't shrink or grow proportionally with the curve length (apart from the start, the animation starts at a point where the curve is still shorter than the tip length, sorry).

First of all, this is the result:

[image: animated curve]

And this is the node tree in the *Geometry Nodes* editor.

[image: trim curve nodes]

I used a *Trim Curve* node to animate the growth of the curve. To the *Group Input* I added two more sockets, "Resolution" controls the *Length* parameter of the *Resample Curve* (you could use *Count* as well). The other input "Tip Length" is used to set the length of the tip with the different material in meter.

The *Capture Attribute* node was necessary because plugging the values directly into the consecutive nodes didn't work (I'm not familiar enough with GN to understand why). What I do then with the *Compare Floats* node is comparing if the current part of the curve is less than the full length minus the desired tip length. If the result is true (meaning it's not the tip), the next *Set Material* uses this selection to give this part blue material. The *Boolean* "Not" node gives the tip the glowing red material.

The "Resolution" and "Tip Length" values can be changed in the GN modifier directly. "Resolution" needs to be high enough so that the tip size doesn't jump between control points.

In the end I animated the *End* value in the *Trim Curve* node. And here's the file:

[image]

I would have liked to do it just with a material in the *Shader Editor*. On a Bézier curve you can use the *Texture Coordinate* node set to UV - the X value moves along the curve - to drive the mix between two materials. This would have been easy, but unfortunately it's always in the 0 to 1 range and I can't get the curve length into the material to multiply with, so I couldn't find out how to set the tip to a fixed size.

Comment: While I remain hopeful for a Material solution, this is awesome work @Gordon Brinkman :) While I was trying to come up with my own answer, I tried the UV Tex. Coords, and that's an improvement for sure.

Comment: @OroNZ I actually would like to use UV tex coordinates, but it's really annoying I cannot set them to absolute length somehow to keep the tip at the same size all the time. I thought I could simply calculate the length in GN and give it as output value, the problem is: if I bevel the curve outside GN so that it has a thickness, GN takes it as mesh and can't measure the length. If I convert Mesh to Curve in GN, the whole mesh gets measured so instead of e.g. 12 m you then have 400. Creating a mesh with a profile in GN doesn't give you the UV tex coordinates... the interaction could be better.

Comment: I hear you. The same problem manifests as inconsistent speed in the Shader Editor. My curve has several points. If the points are relatively close, or very close, the speed of material travel slows down. That's because speed (and material 'length') is measured by point-to-point curve resolution, rather than the absolute length of the curve. See demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcnmtlLZ790

Comment: ... Basically, I think we're both after a curve attribute called "Absolute Length" or similar :)